# hyperlink tag not printing correctly in php

Tags: php

Please check this (I'm new to PHP), I just want to add an image to an existing php code for the nav menu.

Previous code is

```
$html .= "<li>\n <a href='".$menu['items'][$itemId]->menu_link."'>".$menu['items'][$itemId]->display_name."</a>\n</li> \n";
```

Which is displaying correct with the Menu name, and here i want to put an image so my code is as below

```
$html .= "<li>\n <a href='".$menu['items'][$itemId]->menu_link."'><img src='../assets/img/live_view.png'/>".$menu['items'][$itemId]->display_name."</a>\n</li> \n";
```

Its not displaying the image correctly but has no errors, is there any fix ?

Comment: Make sure the path is correct

Comment: Path is correct image is coming but others styles breakdown

Comment: What do you mean when you say the image styles are breaking down?

Comment: Ok Check this click on http://tinyurl.com/lncfmd4 the top arrow and you will see the drop-down is not happening, but its working with the first code.

Comment: I suggest you invert ```"```s and ```'```s as per standard attribute should use double-quotes. It's not going to fix your issue though.